# Replace number with text using regex

Tags: regex, markdown

I need to go through a file and replace all instances where an issue is mentioned using the Github convention `#xxx` (where `xxx` is the issue number), with a link to the issue using the `Markdown` format.

So for example, this:

```
#143, #99
```

should be converted into this:

```
[#143](https://github.com/repo/issues/143), [#99](https://github.com/repo/issues/99)
```

I've gotten as far as to being able to select all the issues with three digits using:

```
#..[0-9]
```

but this leaves out the two or one digits issues (ie: `#5` or `#23`)

Is there a way to generalize the above command to select all issues, no matter how many digits they have?

Once this is done, how can I make the replacement to add a link to each issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the regex `#(\d+)` and replace with `[#$1](https://github.com/repo/issues/$1)`

Comment: The first regex isn't working for me Amit, it selects nothing.

Comment: The second one also isn't working, the number gets replaced by `[#](https://github.com/repo/issues/)`. I'm using Sublime BTW, not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: @Gabriel try now. You don't need delimiters that I had used in Sublime

Answer (score 2):

You should use this regex:

```
#[0-9]{1,3}
```

to match a issue # between 1 and 3 digits as `[0-9]{1,3}` will match a number that is 1 to 3 in length.

You can also use use **word boundaries**:

```
#[0-9]+\b
```

Comment: well looks like you beat me :)

Comment: This works great for selecting the issues, thanks anubhava! Any idea how I could replace them with the correct markdown link?

Comment: You should match `#([0-9]+)\b` and replace it by: `[$0](https://github.com/repo/issues/$1)` Where `$0` and `$1` are back-references to the matched data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex for what you are trying to do

```
#[0-9]{1,3}
```